# CSS: Hide parent if all children are hidden

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a list with groups in it, and use CSSOM to dynamically filter the contents using a text field. This is a way to implement a "search" using only CSS.

Unfortunately when the filter filters everything out, the group containers still remain visible. I'd need to also set `display: none` onto them using CSS somehow, otherwise I need to add a bunch of JS to control them.

Is this remotely possible? I know this is a big of a long shot, but is there a selector that can select elements whose children (fitting some selector) all must have a style selected on them?

Is it even possible if I greatly relax the constraints, where this might be a selector that selects elements whose children (fitting some selector) all must have a particular class?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov the iff is a mathematical notion https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if and not a typo. But I'm fine with the edit this way.

Comment: Didn't know that. But "if" is much more familiar for most people. Feel free to edit your own question if you disagree.

Comment: It's interesting that you edited it because I thought to myself when I wrote it "Would it just be better if I just wrote the normal 'if'?" But I had already typed it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's impossible only via CSS:

1. There is [no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector).
2. There is no visibility selector, except something like `:not([style*="display:none"]):not([style*="display: none"])` if you hide elements only using inline CSS.
3. There is no CSS way to know if all children satisfy some condition.

---

This can be solved only using pure JS loops and conditions or via jQuery selectors like `.parent:not(:has(:visible))`.